# Why is the pressure value altered in this gas law numerical?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

When I work through the following problem it is unclear to me why 0.00120 mmHg is converted to 0.00332 mmHg.

> What is the temperature of 0.00332 g of mercury in the gas phase with pressure of 0.00120 mmHg and a volume of 435 L?

I converted the grams of mercury to moles and then used the ideal gas law constant of 62.36 to solve for T. Is there any reason that the pressure of 0.00120 mmHg should be converted to 0.00332 mmHg?

Answer (score 2):

Your tutor is a master of confusion :-D

Would the exercise be easier if the pressure was given in stones per square acre? ;-)

Write down the equation for the ideal gas law again. Pay attention to the units!

Don't let the mercury fool you ;-)

Comment: Uhh... Square acres?  Better to give lengths in knot-seonds...